# Java - Redis: Pool of 300+ connections possible?

Tags: java, redis, connection, pool

I find it hard to create a connection pool in Redis with 300+ connections. I am about use it in a volatile environment in a multi-threaded app. Is anyone experienced with a deployment like this that could help me determine if this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: the question is why do you need to keep all this connections actives at the same time ? Better to close connexion once job performed and not to leave them running. Keep your architecture simple will prevent bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues on the redis side - http://jaksprats.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/12/ shows performance data for up to 64k concurrent connections.

300 is a long way from 64k, but it is a lot closer to the maximum number of threads java can reasonably handle. That varies depending on the hardware you are using, JVM settings, and how much each thread is doing. There isn't enough information in your question to know for sure, but most likely this is where you are running into problems.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into those details.